# How to Install the new Gnome Boxes?

Tags: virtualization, gnome-boxes

How can I install the new virtual machine app Boxes (https://live.gnome.org/Boxes) in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Gnome-boxes cannot be installed on 12.04.

GNOME boxes has not been packaged due to dependency problems. If you want to try out the boxes, try compiling from the source.

For 12.10 and newer it can be installed by simply typing:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-boxes
```

If you are looking to use a newer version, you can consider installing it from the [source tarballs](http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/gnome-boxes/).

Do take note that GNOME boxes is still very much in development.

Answer (score 8):

### Installation on 12.10:

Click on the button:

[image: Install via the software center]

[image]

Comment: In Ubuntu 11.10?

Comment: installing it in 11.10 may cause problems ,thats why i mentioned 12.04

Comment: @EApubs see jokerdino's answer to this question, dependencies are a problem with GNOME boxes within 11.10

Comment: NOTE: GNOME Boxes only runs on the amd64 version of Ubuntu at this time.

Answer (score 1):

First install gnome-boxes and the required dependencies libvirt-bin and qemu-kvm
`sudo apt install libvirt-bin qemu-kvm gnome-boxes`

Then add yourself to the kvm group
`sudo usermod -aG kvm $USER`

Then allow kvm group to run commands and edit the qemu.conf file
`sudo sed -i -e 's/\#group\ =\ "root"/group=kvm/g' /etc/libvirt/qemu.conf`

Answer (score 1):

## Install using Flatpak

```
sudo apt install flatpak
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:alexlarsson/flatpak
sudo apt update
sudo apt install flatpak
```

#### Now use the following command to install GNOME Boxes

```
flatpak install flathub org.gnome.Boxes
```

#### Or use .flatpakref file to install

[GNOME Boxes](https://flathub.org/repo/appstream/org.gnome.Boxes.flatpakref)